# Alterar estilo de um clone

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um botão que ao se clicado, ele cria um quadrado na tela, que é uma div 100x100, como background vermelho. Para que a cada clique aparecesse um novo quadrado, eu utilizei `container.appendChild(clone)` sendo `var clone = quadrado.cloneNode(true)`.

O botão cumpre o que se espera dele, o problema acontece quando eu crio um `quadrado.addEventListener('click', novaCor, false)`. Ao clicar no quadrado ele não executa função nenhuma. Tente fazer um fiddle para mostra, mas o meu botão não funcionou no JsFiddle nem no CodePen.

Segue o JS:

```js
var botao = document.createElement('button', 'clique')
var txtBotao = document.createTextNode('Clique')
var newColor = getRandomColor()
var quadrado = document.createElement('div')
var container = document.querySelector('div')

botao.appendChild(txtBotao)
botao.addEventListener('click', adicionaQuadrado, false)
quadrado.addEventListener('click', novaCor, false)
container.appendChild(botao)

quadrado.style.margin = 10
quadrado.style.width = 100
quadrado.style.height = 100
quadrado.style.backgroundColor = '#f00'

function adicionaQuadrado () {
  var clone = quadrado.cloneNode(true)
  container.appendChild(clone)
  console.log(clone)
}

function novaCor () {
  quadrado.style.backgroundColor = newColor
}

function getRandomColor () {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'
  var color = '#'
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  return color
}
```

Comment: Ao clicar no clone não faz nada?

Comment: Nada. Inclusive coloquei um console.log('foo') para testar, mas não acontece nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você insere um novo elemento no DOM após o carregamento da página, ele não foi inserido no `eventListener` no momento da execução do script porque esse elemento não existia.

O que você pode fazer é adicionar uma classe às `div`s criadas para depois pegar o clique usando `event.target`.

Adicionando uma classe à `div` criada:

```
quadrado.className = "div";
```

Altere o evento selecionando pelo `body` (porque irá encontrar todos os elementos nele, inclusive os criados após o carregamento da página) enviando o objeto via parâmetro para a função `novaCor()`:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   if (event.target.className == 'div'){
      novaCor(event.target);
   }
}, false)
```

Função `novaCor()` ficará assim, recebendo o elemento:

```
function novaCor (e) {
  e.style.backgroundColor = newColor
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var botao = document.createElement('button', 'clique')
var txtBotao = document.createTextNode('Clique')
var newColor = getRandomColor()
var quadrado = document.createElement('div')
quadrado.className = "div";
var container = document.querySelector('div')

botao.appendChild(txtBotao)
botao.addEventListener('click', adicionaQuadrado, false)
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   if (event.target.className == 'div'){
      novaCor(event.target);
   }
}, false)
container.appendChild(botao)

quadrado.style.margin = "10px"
quadrado.style.width = "100px"
quadrado.style.height = "100px"
quadrado.style.backgroundColor = '#f00'

function adicionaQuadrado () {
  var clone = quadrado.cloneNode(true)
  container.appendChild(clone)
 // console.log(clone)
}

function novaCor (e) {
  e.style.backgroundColor = newColor
}

function getRandomColor () {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'
  var color = '#'
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  return color
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Seu código ainda tem erro nessas linhas:

```
quadrado.style.margin = 10
quadrado.style.width = 100
quadrado.style.height = 100
```

Estilos de valores no CSS devem ter uma unidade de medida, como `px`:

```
quadrado.style.margin = "10px"
quadrado.style.width = "100px"
quadrado.style.height = "100px"
```

Por isso não funcionava nos JSFiddle, CodePen e nem aqui.